# While testing python max recursion depth, why am I hitting RuntimeError multiple times?

Tags: python, cpython

I was trying to experimentally determine Python's maximum recursion depth with the following code:

```
def recursive(i):
    i = i + 1
    try:
        recursive(i)
    except RuntimeError:
        print 'max depth == %d' % i
        exit(0)

recursive(0)
```

But when I ran it, this happened:

```
[ hive ~ ]$ python recursive.py 
max depth == 999
max depth == 998
max depth == 997
max depth == 996
max depth == 995
max depth == 994
```

Why is my program not exiting right away when it encountered `RuntimeError` the first time, but continued to run for 5 more calls to `recursive()`?

Comment: Perhaps printing the message of the exception could give you a clue.

Comment: works as expected for me

Comment: And you could just use [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) to get the same information. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters reproduced with 2.7

Comment: @alko: I tested this with 2.7.5 on Mac OS X.

Comment: And presumably there is a `from sys import exit` at the top here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 2.7.2 win, 2.7.2 and 2.7.3 ubuntu

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on Windows, when running from command line :-)

Comment: Ah, AH! `exit()` is **not** `sys.exit`. It is the `exit()` callable set by the `site` module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters afaik exit is a built in.

Comment: @alko: No, it isn't. It is a python function from the `site` module, meant for use in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: If you replace `exit(0)` with `sys.exit()` it works as expected. If you instead use `raise SystemExit(0)` (which is what `site.setquit().Quitter.__call__()` does), then you get *two* prints. This is the Python stack unwinding.

Comment: A minor addition to the discussion, exit is not a straightforward call to the libc exit, check this blog entry http://clalance.blogspot.ie/2011/01/exiting-python-program.html to

Comment: @MartijnPieters true about site part, but it is imported for a script as well (ok, except for -S option, but definitly is imported for `python test.py` usage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the [`exit()` function the Python `site` module sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module) for use in the interactive interpreter.

This is **Python code** you are calling, not C code. This triggers the recursion depth exception handler a few more times until you are far enough away from the stack limit.

When you are right up against the limit, trying to call `exit()` fails because you hit the stack limit. So a `RuntimeError` is raised, falling back a call to `998`. Here you try to call `exit()` again, which tries to do some more work raising the `RuntimeError` again, falling back another level, etc. until there is enough stack space left to finally call `raise SystemExit()` in the python function.

Use [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) instead to avoid adding more strain to the stack.

Or, for future reference, use the [`sys.getrecursionlimit()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) to just ask Python directly what the limit is.

Answer (score 4):

Runtime error is catched in recursive(999) `try`-`except`, but reraised by `exit(0)`. Latter is roughly equivalent to `raise SystemExit(0)` modulo some additional calls, those calls makes `RuntimeError` happen again, see it as following code:

```
def recursive(i):
    try:
        i = i + 1
        recursive(i)
    except RuntimeError as exc:
        print 'max depth == %d' % i
        try:
            exit(0)
        except RuntimeError:
            print 'RuntimeError in exit'

recursive(0)
```

outputs

```
max depth == 999
RuntimeError in exit
```

So runtime error is catched again within recursive(998) and so on, totaling 5 catches until the moment your stack is unwinded far away to `exit(0)` be able not to raise an RuntimeError.